# how to validate that a name entered using mvc doesn't exist in database

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i am using sql server which is case sensitive. How can i convert the data so that it may be validated without being case sensitive

CODE:-

```
using (var kk = new TeamRepository(context))
            {
                var data = new Team();
                var find = kk.GetAll().ToString();

                if (find.Any(x => x.TeamName == apview.TeamName))
                {
                    return false;
                }
                else
                {
                    var _pointrepo = new PointsRepositotry(context);

                    if (image != null)
                    {
                        apview.ImageMimeType = image.ContentType;
                        apview.TeamLogo = new byte[image.ContentLength];
                        image.InputStream.Read(apview.TeamLogo, 0, image.ContentLength);
                    }
                    data.TeamLogo = apview.TeamLogo;
                    data.TeamName = apview.TeamName;
                    data.TeamEmail = apview.TeamEmail;
                    data.Contact_Number = apview.ContactNumber;
                    data.TeamNickName = apview.TeamNickName;
                    data.YearEstablished = apview.YearEstablished;
                    var points = new Points();
                    points.TeamName = apview.TeamName;

                    data.ImageMimeType = apview.ImageMimeType;
                   return kk.Insert(data);
                    //_pointrepo.Insert(points);
                }
```

Comment: `find.Any(x => x.TeamName.ToLower() == apview.TeamName.ToLower()))`

Answer (score 0):

you can use **ToLower**

```
find.Any(x => x.TeamName.ToLower() == apview.TeamName.ToLower())
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78f86at%28v=vs.110%29.aspx